# -all_load AND -ObjC cause problems with other libraries

Tags: ios, catchoom-sdk

I'm using **CatchoomSDK** in my app, and now I want to use socialize framework.

Socialize needs `-all_load` AND `-ObjC` flags and with these flag i am getting:

> duplicate symbol error.

if I remove the `-all_load` flags, the app crashes with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString socializeTrim]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 2):

After long research got the solution steps to resolve the issue:

1. Remove -all_load flag from Other Linker Flags in Build Phase
2. Added -force_load followed by path of Socialize library(Means Socialize.a).

For Example

```
-force_load $(SOURCE_ROOT)/Socialize.embeddedframework/Socialize.framework/Versions/A/Socialize
```